# Is there a way to dynamically render a hidden version of a django field in a template?

Tags: django, django-templates

Introspection tells me that django fields have a "hidden_widget" attribute.  Maybe its not this attribute's given purpose, but its mere existence tempts me to use it in a template to conditionally render a hidden widget. 
e.g.,

```
{% if some condition %} 
   {{ form.my_field }} 
{% else %} 
   {{ form.my_field.hidden_widget }} 
{% endif %}
```

But this doesn't work. Is it possible to use the hidden widget this way? What am I missing?

I realize I could do this by dynamically setting the widget in the **init** of my custom Form class based on some custom kwarg for the conditional, which I pass in to it, but the above solution (dynamically rendering the hidden widget in the template) would be way simpler, if its available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was close, but using the wrong function.  The answer, for those who are interested, is:

```
{{ form.my_field.as_hidden }}
```

Comment: Figured this out by looking at Django source code.  I'm not sure if I've seen this documented anywhere.  If someone posts an answer with a link to some sort of documentation for the as_hidden function, I'll mark it as accepted, since I'd prefer not to accept my own answer.